# MVC4 and Entity Framework Inheritance and Include

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, include

I have some simple objects

```
public class DataClass
{
    public int id;
    public string Data;
}

public class Job()
{
   public int id;
}

public class NewJob : Job
{
   public  DateTime StartDate;
   public  DataClass data;
}
```

I have then defined them in my dBContext()

```
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }        
    public DbSet<DataClass> DataClass { get; set; }
```

Now if I use the following code

```
NewJob job = (NewJob) db.Jobs.Find(id);
```

This works fine but returns "data" as null

I know I define the class with the virtual keyword and it works and populates the "data" object.

```
public class NewJob : Job
{
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public virtual DataClass data;
}
```

But in my case I "normally" do not want the "data" object to be populated. So I need to load it on demand.

If I try something like

```
NewJob job = (NewJob)db.Jobs.Include("data").First();
```

I get an exception

**A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Models.Job' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'data'.**

I guess this is because it is looking at "job" and not "NewJob" when it is trying to do the include.

I also do not like the include with a string - no design time checking.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to convert data object to your domain object via type casting which is a very bad idea. What you want to do is grab your data object, instantiate your domain object, and map your data values to the domain object using some type of helper class. A very helpful tool I have been using is Automapper. Its a tool that will allow you to map one object to another. It also allows the use of regular expression to help with the mappings if the naming conventions between the 2 objects are different.

Comment: Hi - you say that type casting is a very bad idea - why is this? Logically this is what I want to do with an object.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, been pretty busy. You only want to use type casting when you want to convert an object to its base model or vice versa. To cast one object to a totally different object with no polymorphic relationship is bad practice and a bad idea as it can introduce unhandled exceptions/errors that you will have no control over. You are better off doing some type of mapping in which case you will have more control over your conversions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Entity Framework Code First and want to create instances of derived classes/entities you should do the following:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    var newJob = db.Jobs.Create<NewJob>();
    newJob.data.Data = "some data for a new job"; // this is string Data from DataClass

    db.Jobs.Add(newJob);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of searching I found the following which can help.

If you include the System.Data.Entity namespace in your using clause then you can use the extension method **.Include()** after **OfType<>()** which is not normally available.

Slightly different code sample

```
 using System.Data.Entity; 

 NewJob job = (NewJob)db.Jobs.OfType<NewJob>().Include(m => m.data).Where(x => x.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

This seems to be working for me in the example I used.